# FileNotFoundException when reading file using FileInfo

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, file, fileinfo

I'm currently using fileinfo to use a xsd file in a xml validator.

I have 3 projects, a GUI, interface, project. A input project and a testproject.

Inside the input project i have a class that creates a FileInfo Object based on a path to a file that is also inside the same object:

```
new FileInfo(@"Xsd\Version_813\kvppt-8130.xsd")
```

This gives me trouble when i'm running my tests and my GUI. For example when i start my GUI, sometimes the code works and there is no problem but other times FileInfo will search the Bin/debug folder from the GUI project and the XSD isnt there.

I know that this is intended but is there a way to make this work for the unittest Project and the GUI project.

I have tried the following:

```
var executingFileInfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var path = executingFileInfo.DirectoryName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + @"Xsd\Version_813\kvppt-8130.xsd";
Return new FileInfo(path);
```

But this isn't the solution because it will still pick the startup project.

--- Edit:

After trying some of the suggestions in the comments i found out that my problem is a bit diffrent. I found out that if i press rebuild all before running my application, the files are always copied to their correct folder. It only fails if i just run the application.

Properties of the files are on "Copy always"

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile. You should be seeing errors of "error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence".

Comment: True, copy paste error i made. I corrected it. The string is in my code a variable but i changed it to make it more clear.

Comment: use `executingFileInfo.Exists` and `executingFileInfo.FullName` where it is expected.

Comment: Option one, make it an absolute path to the file instead of a relative path.  Option two, move the path to the configuration files so you can use different relative paths based on what is running.

Comment: Option three, unless you really need it as a separate file, use an embedded resource instead.

Comment: Instead of method producing file you can make one which works with any stream, then unit test can supply memory stream to test it. Then there is no hassle with files (is it a good idea to have IO tasks in unit tests?) or relative file names. Or, well, just make path a parameter.

Comment: A little off topic, but consider using `Path.Combine` for forming paths, e.g. `var path = Path.Combine(executingFileInfo.DirectoryName, @"Xsd\Version_813\kvppt-8130.xsd")`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I tried them but i think my problem is something diffrent than origanlly defined. When starting my application the files are not always coppied to the debug folder. Thats why its not finding the files. If i rebuild and run it will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...sometimes the code works and there is no problem but other times
>   FileInfo will search the Bin/debug folder from the GUI project and the
>   XSD isnt there.

Make sure on the properties of the file (from within Visual Studio) you have "Copy to Output Directory" set to either "copy always" or "copy if newer"

Comment: I have my properties on Copy always. But i have a feeling that the file is not always copied to the folder.

Comment: @JorisMathijssen In the post-compile build section of the project (or solution)'s properties, you can put instructions, such as a copy instruction.